# specify the location of a window using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am working on a script that will set up most of the programs I use during work.
I started simple like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

thunderbird &
utox &
firefox http://www.stackoverflow&
```

it is already pretty nice, but lubuntu doesn't memorize the position. so it is all messed up and i have to position every window. 
I am looking for a possibility to move every window using the very same script. I found the -geometry parameter, but it is application specific and e.g. firefox doesn't support something like that.

as I have 2 monitors there has to be the ability to also control the screen the window shows up.

A bonus would be to also set up windows on my 2nd virtual desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably quite dependent on your window manager - it may be possible to assign default positions for specific applications. Either way, I'm not sure that this is on topic here as it isn't really a programming question.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/setting-the-window-dimensions-of-a-running-application`